# Python: How do I remove an element from a list of lists given the number of elements?

Tags: python, list

Example list (the actual list is VERY long):

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'],['a'],['a', 'b', 'c'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['a'], ['a', 'b']]
```

How do I remove lists with only < 2 elements within the larger list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[x for x in list if len(x)>=2]
```

x represents the lists which comprise your list. The whole construct is called a list comprehension. It creates a new list based on the logic featured within the square brackets. To translate my code to English...

"Create a new list with the all sublists from the old list, but only include the sublist if the length of the sublist is two or more."

Comment: Just to clarify, "x for x" is just a term to represent all lists inside the main list? Can "x" be changed for variable or must it be "x"?

Comment: The first x represents the new element which forms in your new list. The second represents the elements of the old list. The part before the for is the expresion which will be present in your new list (e.g. replace the first x with len(x) and this will become clear)

Answer (score 3):

You can try out this simple `list comprehension`:

```
lst = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['a'],['a', 'b', 'c'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['a'], ['a', 'b']]

lst = [elem for elem in lst if len(elem) >= 2]

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']]
```

Comment: Here you are maiking a copy of original list that will increase the memory usage, as OP already mention that list is too long

Comment: Ok @anuragal...I have edited my code.